# How to include Oauth2 auth urls in Swagger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-swagger, drf-spectacular

I use Django drf-spectacular OAuth Toolkit for an Oauth2 password flow. Unfortunately, Swagger doesn't recognize the auth URLs.
This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

# schema
path("api/schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(api_version='v1'), name="schema"),
path(
    "api/schema/swagger/",
    SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="schema"),
    name="swagger-ui",
),
path(
    "api/schema/redoc/",
    SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name="schema"),
    name="redoc",
),
path("api/oauth/", include("apps.main.oauth.urls", namespace="oauth2_provider")),
]
```

How can I fix thit?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically, show you you are adding swagger to your django project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it available to swagger you have to override the Oauth API, for example, override the token API and and write an inline serializer in the @extend_schema and pass the post method.

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema, inline_serializer
from oauth2_provider.views.application import TokenView

class TokenApiView(TokenView, APIView):

@extend_schema(
    request=inline_serializer(
        name="InlineTokenSerializer",
        fields={
            "username": serializers.CharField(),
            "password": serializers.CharField(),
            "grant_type": serializers.CharField(required=False),
            "Scope": serializers.CharField(required=False),
            "client_id": serializers.CharField(),
        },
    )
)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The oauth toolkit does provides regular html views, which are not DRF views. Therefore they do not appear in the schema because spectacular can only parse any of the DRF-type views.

What you need to do is add some settings that direct SwaggerUI to those auth views:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    # Oauth2 related settings. used for example by django-oauth2-toolkit.
    # https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#oauth-flows-object
    'OAUTH2_FLOWS': [],
    'OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL': None,
    'OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL': None,
    'OAUTH2_REFRESH_URL': None,
    'OAUTH2_SCOPES': None,
    # other spectcular settings
}
```

So 3 steps are basically required to make this fully functional:

- Add the views to urlpatterns for `oauth2_provider` (as you did)
- Make sure the views have `OAuth2Authentication` and the corresponding `permission_classes` (directly or via DRF default setting)
- Add the settings as outlined above. You may not need all of them depending on the supported flows you have to set at least some URLs there.