# def-spectacular not generate schema urls for django-oauth-toolkit urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm trying to generate Open API schema.

settings.py:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
  'TITLE': 'TMC Authentication API',
  'DESCRIPTION': 'Description',
  'VERSION': '1.0.0',
  'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
  'SWAGGER_UI_DIST': 'SIDECAR',
  'SWAGGER_UI_FAVICON_HREF': 'SIDECAR',
  'REDOC_DIST': 'SIDECAR'
}
```

urls.py:

```
path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
path('api/swagger/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger'),
path('api/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc'),
path('api/auth/token/', oauth2_provider.views.TokenApiView.as_view(), name="token"),
...
```

When run `python manage.py spectacular --file schema.yaml` the oauth2_provider urls are not generated.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Schemas for the oauth2_provider views are not generated automatically. You will need to subclass the views so that drf-spectacular can generate information for them. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71261293/1785448